# What is the Largest Number of Claims in any Granted Patent?

Tags: claims

In my patent searches, I have found some patents with upwards of 300 claims. This has me impressed. I'm wondering what the *world record* for the greatest number of claims in any patent is. Does anyone know the patent that holds this record?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is an official world record, but doing a quick search using [AcclaimIP](http://www.acclaimip.com), here are the top 3*:

1. 887: [US6684189](http://www.google.com/patents/US6684189) Apparatus and method using front-end network gateways and search criteria for efficient quoting at a remote location
2. 868: [US5095054](http://www.google.com/patents/US5095054) Polymer compositions containing destructurized starch
3. 803: [US7096160](http://www.google.com/patents/US7096160) System and method for measuring and monitoring wireless network performance in campus and indoor environments

*Granted patents, US/JP/EP/DE

Answer (score 1):

### [US20030173072A1](http://google.com/patents/US20030173072A1) (application)

- **Title:** Forming openings in a hydrocarbon containing formation using magnetic tracking
- **Publication Date:** Sep 18, 2003
- **Claims:** 8,958

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a patent application and not a granted patent, as the question is asking for. I've formatted this answer a bit, and specifically indicated that fact in the header.